Message payloads are being concatenated with SignalR
I've got a .NET Core app using SignalR that sends a message to clients on connection containing application settings and so on. For whatever reason, SignalR also sends an empty message on connection; the payload is just {}. It's unclear to me why SignalR sends that message.
Occasionally (one in five to one in 25, depending on the environment), that empty message and the application settings message are concatenated together and sent as one message, and the connection.on method in the code below doesn't fire. I presume this has something to do with the timing of the connection from the client, but I have no proof of that and I'm not reliably able to reproduce the issue. The message looks like this in Chrome dev tools:

You can see the {} of the first message plus a framing delimiter followed by the SignalR envelope of the second message. SignalR reports no error on either the server or client. Has anyone encountered this before? Anyone have a fix for why the client doesn't handle these concatenated messages? Things I've tried:

Reworking the back end code to avoid using Clients.Caller and instead send a message based on connection ID.
Adding a custom formatter on the client to remove the prepended empty message. This doesn't work, presumably because SignalR doesn't recognize this message as containing a valid payload and silently ignores it.

As I mentioned above, I suspect the timing of the calls is significant, so I've contemplated adding a 100ms delay to sending my application settings message, but that feels hacky and I'd rather avoid that if I can.
Startup:
services.AddSignalR();

...

app.UseEndpoints(
    endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        endpoints.MapHub<MyHub>(Url.DefaultHub);
    });

Server hub:

public sealed class MyHub(IAppSettingsChannel appSettingsChannel) : Hub
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The event handler representing when a user connects to the web socket. This method will be called for every user connection.
    /// </summary>
    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        // Send app settings when a new user connects or an existing user reconnects.
        await appSettingsChannel.Send(Clients.Caller);

        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
}

Server channel:

public class AppSettingsChannel : IAppSettingsChannel
{
    private static HubChannel Channel => HubChannel.AppSettings;

    internal AppSettingsModel AppSettings => new(...);

    public async Task Send(ISingleClientProxy caller)
    {
        await caller.SendAsync(Channel, AppSettings);
    }
}

Client hub:
export default class Hub {
    /** The underlying web socket connection. */
    private static connection: HubConnection | null = null;

    /** The url that all websocket connections go through, with specific channel urls for different hubs. */
    private static defaultHubUrl: string = '/web-socket';

    /** The period of time to retry the web socket connection more frequently. */
    private static initialRetryPeriodMilliseconds: number = 60 * 1000;

    /** The shorter duration for retrying the web socket connection during the initial retry period. */
    private static initialRetryMilliseconds: number = 5 * 1000;

    /** The longer duration for retrying the web socket connection during the */
    private static continuousRetryMilliseconds: number = 30 * 1000;

    /**
     * Listens for messages on the provided channel. If no connection is established with the server-side socket,
     * one is created.
     * @param channel The channel on which to listen for server-side messages.
     * @param onMessage The callback function to execute when a message is received on the channel.
     */
    static async on<T>(channel: HubChannel, onMessage: (data: T) => void) {
        // If the connection to the server-side web socket has not yet been established, connect now.
        if (!this.connection)
            this.connection = await this.openConnection();

        // Run provided callback when a message on the provided channel is received.
        this.connection.on(channel.value, (msg: T) => {
            onMessage(msg);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Opens a connection to the server-side web socket.
     * @returns The established connection.
     */
    static async openConnection(): Promise<HubConnection> {
        // Open the connection to the web socket.
        this.connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl(this.defaultHubUrl)
            .withAutomaticReconnect({
                // Retry a reconnect every for a shorter duration during the initial retry period then a longer duration thereafter.
                nextRetryDelayInMilliseconds: (retryContext) => (
                    retryContext.elapsedMilliseconds < this.initialRetryPeriodMilliseconds ? this.initialRetryMilliseconds : this.continuousRetryMilliseconds;
                )
            })
            .build();

        // If an error is provided when the connection is closed, log that error to the console.
        this.connection.onclose(async (error) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error('Connection to hub closed with error:', error);
                const apiError = normalizeError(error);
                await logErrorSafe(apiError);
            }
        });

        // Start the connection.
        await this.connection.start();

        return this.connection;
    }
}

Thanks for reading.

Why do you think something is wrong? You said everything is working as expected. And this is expected behavior. The {} is the handshake response, it may contain information in case of a failure, or in future versions. The concatenated messages are also expected, and is why there is a message delimitator.

The code isn't working as expected because the client-side connection.on method's callback doesn't fire when a message that contains two payloads is received. Even with a custom formatter provided to the client-side SignalR connection builder (not shown), no callback is triggered so I have no opportunity to parse the message manually. I've updated the question to indicate that the concatenated message payloads don't trigger the client-side connection callback.

Call connection.on before connection.start
